# How can I fix Recyclerview item deletion display error

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I have a recyclerview. There are city names in the recyclerview and when I long click, I want to delete it from the recyclerview. I wrote some code in adapter class. When I click on the city names, I can delete them, but when I view the recyclerview again, the city names I deleted appear again. How can I fix this ?

**My adapter class**

```
public class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.MyViewHolder>  {

ArrayList<City> arrayList;
Context context;

public Adapter(ArrayList<City> arrayList ,Context context ){
    this.arrayList = arrayList;
    this.context = context;

}

@NonNull
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    RecyclerviewRowBinding recyclerviewRowBinding = RecyclerviewRowBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()),parent,false);
    return new MyViewHolder(recyclerviewRowBinding);

}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull Adapter.MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

    holder.binding.MytxtCities.setText(arrayList.get(position).cityName);


    holder.itemView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
            builder.setIcon(R.drawable.warningicon);
            builder.setMessage("Are you sure that you want to delete "+arrayList.get(position).cityName);
            builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    arrayList.remove(position);
                    notifyItemRemoved(position);
                    notifyItemRangeChanged(position,arrayList.size());
                }
            }).setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                }
            }).show();

            return true;
        }
    });


    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        Intent intent = new Intent(holder.itemView.getContext(),MainActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("citId",arrayList.get(position).id);
        holder.itemView.getContext().startActivity(intent);
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return arrayList.size();
}



public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView Mytxt_cities;
    private RecyclerviewRowBinding binding;

    public MyViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerviewRowBinding binding) {
        super(binding.getRoot());
        this.binding = binding;
        Mytxt_cities = itemView.findViewById(R.id.Mytxt_cities);



    }


}
```

}

**My recyclerview class is cities class**

```
public class cities extends AppCompatActivity {

RecyclerView recyclerView ;
ArrayList<City> cityArrayList;
Adapter cityadapter;
ImageView cities_back_icon;



public void init(){

    cities_back_icon = findViewById(R.id.Id_cities_back_icon);
    cities_back_icon_click_register();

    cityArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerview_id);



    SQLGet_Data();

}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_cities);
    init();


}

private void cities_back_icon_click_register(){

    cities_back_icon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(cities.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}

private void SQLGet_Data(){
    try {

        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.openOrCreateDatabase("City",MODE_PRIVATE,null);
        Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT*FROM city",null);
        int idIx = cursor.getColumnIndex("id");
        int nameIx = cursor.getColumnIndex("cityname");

        while(cursor.moveToNext()){
            String cityname = cursor.getString(nameIx);
            int id = cursor.getInt(idIx);
            City city = new City(cityname,id);
            cityArrayList.add(city);
        }
        cityadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        cursor.close();
    }

    catch (Exception e ){
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
                 /*---------------------- set recyclerview-----------------------------*/

    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(cities.this));
    cityadapter = new Adapter(cityArrayList,this);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(cityadapter);





/*--------------------------We drew a line between the data in the recyclerview------------------------------------*/

    DividerItemDecoration dividerItemDecoration = new DividerItemDecoration(recyclerView.getContext(), DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL);
    Drawable drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.custom_divider);
    dividerItemDecoration.setDrawable(drawable);
    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(dividerItemDecoration);

}
```

}

Comment: You are retrieving the data from a SQL DB but deleting the item only from the list. To completely remove the item so that it never shows again, you'll have to remove it from the db as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are only deleting the cities from your `ArrayList` that is inside your adapter. But those cities still remain in your SQL database. Then when you restart the Activity your ArrayList will be created with the data of your SQL database, where those deleted cities still exist.

To delete cities consistently you need to delete the cities not only in your adapter but also in your SQL database.

Comment: ok. I will try this thank you